# JSON ParseError unexpected token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl, httparty

I'm trying to consume an API within a big loop. The code is pretty straightforward

```
    Video.find_each(:batch_size => 50) do |video|

        # video_details = HTTParty.get("http://www.domain.com/webmasters/video_by_id?id=#{video.video_id}&thumbsize=medium")
        video_details = Curl::Easy.perform("http://www.domain.com/webmasters/video_by_id?id=#{video.video_id}&thumbsize=medium")

        video_data = video_details.body_str

        video_details = JSON.parse( video_data )

        # video.publish_date = video_details['publish_date']



        # video.save
    end
```

**it works fine for first 16 iterations**, but the it throws this error

`JSON::ParserError  784: unexpected token at '<html><head><script type="text/javascript">`

Any idea why does it happen after 16th call?